# jQuery Tools CDN not working?

Tags: jquery

I have just tried to use the jQuery Tools lib and tried to download it from CDN but it's not there anymore. 
Does someone by chance have it? (Tabs, Scrollable, Overlay)

Comment: what url are you using to reference the CDN?

Comment: This one : http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js; And the others that you can find on flowplayer page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a [raised issue](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/674) in GitHub.

This one works for me, I'm in the UK:

http://jquerytools.flowplayer.netdna-cdn.com/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: It appears to be down again today; this brought our admin down as well.  The Flowplayer CDN worked like a charm though.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery tools CDN server(http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js) is down. And there [demos](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html) also not working. hope they will fix the issue.

Comment: yes and still their [documentation](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) refer to that url.

Comment: Weird, why would their server be down ? I find this lib quite useful sometimes, but indeed it's a bit outdated. Perhaps they're rebuilding it or launching a new version.

Comment: Perhaps they don't have any money to pay for hosting?